# How to Use posix_spawn() in Java

Tags: java, solaris

I've inherited a legacy application that uses `ProcessBuilder.start()` to execute a script on a Solaris 10 server.

Unfortunately, this script call fails due to a memory issue, as documented [here](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/subprocess/subprocess.html)

Oracle's recommendation is to use `posix_spawn()` since, under the covers, `ProcessBuilder.start()` is using `fork/exec`.

I have been unable to find any examples (e.g., how to call `"myScript.sh"`)

using `posix_spawn()` in Java, or even what are the packages that are required.

Could you please, point me to a simple example on how to use `posix_spawn()` in Java?

Comment: i have not tried this, but this service wrapper library appears to provide a Runtime.exec() replacement with support for posix_spawn. 

http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/jdoc/org/tanukisoftware/wrapper/WrapperManager.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to familiarize yourself with [JNI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/index.html) first.  Learn how to call out into a native routine from Java code.  Once you do - you can look at [this](http://www.thatisjava.com/hotspot-virtual-machine/157517/) example and see if it helps with your issue.  Of particular interest to you is:

```
if( (RC=posix_spawn(&pid, spawnedArgs[0], NULL, NULL, spawnedArgs, NULL)) !=0 ){
    printf("Error while executing posix_spawn(), Return code from posix_spawn()=%d",RC);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Recent version of Java 7 and 8 support `posix_spawn` internally.

command line option

```
-Djdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism=POSIX_SPAWN
```

or enable at runtime

```
System.setProperty("jdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism", "POSIX_SPAWN");
```

I'm a little confused as to which Java version/OS combinations have this enabled by default, but I'm sure you could test and find out pretty quickly whether setting this option makes a difference.

For reference, to go back to the old `fork` method simply use

```
-Djdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism=fork
```

To prove whether this option is respected in your JVM version use

```
-Djdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism=dummy
```

and you will get an error next time you `exec`. This way you know the JVM is receiving this option.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative, which does not require JNI, is to create a separate "process spawner" application. I would probably have this application expose an RMI interface, and create a wrapper object that is a drop-in replacement for `ProcessBuilder`.

You might also want to consider having this "spawner" application be the thing that starts your legacy application.

Comment: Do you know of any open source implementations of this?  I'm on the verge of writing one myself, but I'd rather use a library if one exists.

Answer (score 2):

A much simpler solution would be to keep your code unchanged and simply add more virtual memory to your server.

i.e.:

```
mkfile 2g /somewhere/swap-1
swap -a /somewhere/swap-1
```

Edit: To clarify as the link present in the question is now broken:

the question is about a system out of virtual memory due to the JVM being forked. Eg, assuming the JVM uses 2 GB of VM, an extra 2 GB of VM is required for the fork to succeed on Solaris. There is no pagination involved here, just memory reservation. Unlike the Linux kernel which by default overcommits memory, Solaris makes sure allocated memory is backed by either RAM or swap. As there is not enough swap available, fork is failing. Enlarging the swap allows the fork to succeed without any performance impact. Just after the fork, the exec "unreserves" this 2GB of RAM and revert to a situation identical to the posix_spawn one.

See also this [page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris10/subprocess-136439.html) for an explanation about memory allocation under Solaris and other OSes.

Comment: the op asked how to use posix spawn, not how to add virtual memory

Comment: @kritzikratzi The OP exposed a problem and what I suggest is a much simpler and less intrusive workaround than what he is exploring. Nothing that deserve a down vote.

Comment: swapping to harddisk is not a viable option if speed matter only a tiny bit, thats why i downvoted.

Comment: add to that: your answer doesn't even fix the problem, because adding swap space has nothing to do with it. you'll have to increase the Xmx and Xms limit, the lack of swap space might or might not be the problem.

Comment: @kritzikratzi I'm afraid you are missing the point. The issue is not related to Xmx/Xms settings the way you think it is. Increasing Xmx would actually worsen the java application behavior, not the other way around. In addition, increasing the swap space would have zero impact on performance here.

Comment: hm... maybe i am missing the point. if there's no impact on performance that should mean the swap space is never used. but if the swap space is never used, why would increasing it solve the problem?

Comment: @kritzikratzi Because the the question is about a system out of virtual memory due to the JVM being forked. Eg, if the JVM uses 2 GB of VM, an extra 2 GB of VM is required. There is absolutely no pagination involved here, just memory reservation. Solaris makes sure allocated memory is backed by either RAM or swap. As there is not enough swap available, fork is failing. Enlarging the swap allows the fork to succeed without any performance impact. Just after the fork, the exec "unreserves" this 2GB of RAM and revert to a situation identical to the posix_spawn one.

Comment: maybe add this to your answer :) also: do you know about the situation on other OSs?

Comment: @kritzikratzi Done. Linux in its default configuration doesn't check memory availability at reservation time (i.e. overcommit memory). Other Unix might or might not overcommit memory. Windows doesn't use fork in the first place.